# i saved credentials.json file in and remaining python files all in single folder

Tags: python, spyder

[I saved credentials file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INNNZ.png) in and remaining python files all in single folder only but still i am getting no folder named credentials.json is found how to solve this error
can you please help me how to solve this error
from_json_keyfile_name
with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json

[image]

For spreadsheets i wrote the following code:

```
import datetime,gspread,random
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import emailing as em 

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json',scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("finalface").sheet1
```

Comment: Please dont upload images upload code with correct formatting 

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You just try this:

```
import json

with open('path_to_file/credentials.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: no its not working

Comment: Can you send us the code correctly formatted and where are the files involved?

Comment: File "C:\Users\MY PC\Documents\Face-recognition-based-attendance-system-master\face recognition source code\spreadsheet.py", line 7, in <module>
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("project-332110-8771419f4715.json",scope)

  File "G:\anaconda\envs\face\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 219, in from_json_keyfile_name
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json' but i saved the json file in my documents/facerecognition dource code folder only

Comment: It's hard to understand this way. But I see .py file a .json one are in differents paths.

Comment: it is solved thank you

Comment: I'm happy for that!! Good luck!